# Dynamic library size bigger than static library and sum of linked objects size, how comes?

Tags: opencv, gcc, android-ndk, shared-libraries, static-libraries

**[See edit, it seems the extra size comes from debugging symbols added at linking time, but the reason why this happens is still unclear!]**

I am cross compiling OpenCV 2.4.11 Ubuntu x86 64bit -> armeabi.

I am using the toolchain available here https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html, choosing the 4.9 compiler.

When I compile the dynamic libraries, they get considerably *bigger* than the static library. Examples:

```
 3793082 Mar 12 17:21 libopencv_core.a
 6131716 Mar 12 17:29 libopencv_core.so
  446060 Mar 12 17:22 libopencv_highgui.a
 5510352 Mar 12 17:30 libopencv_highgui.so
 3477794 Mar 12 17:21 libopencv_imgproc.a
 5325504 Mar 12 17:29 libopencv_imgproc.so
   38004 Mar 12 17:19 libopencv_info.so
  844990 Mar 12 17:21 libopencv_ml.a
 3827136 Mar 12 17:29 libopencv_ml.so
  747744 Mar 12 17:22 libopencv_objdetect.a
 2370188 Mar 12 17:30 libopencv_objdetect.so
  405920 Mar 12 17:22 libopencv_video.a
 2196268 Mar 12 17:30 libopencv_video.so
```

For the static library the size corresponds more or less to the total size of the object files. Example for core and highgui.

```
du -chs `find -iname \*.o|grep opencv_core.dir`
[...]
3,5M    total

du -chs `find -iname \*.o|grep opencv_highgui.dir`
[...]
352K    total
```

The same happens if I build with make or ninja.

There is just a small difference in the compiler flags at build time, but if I check the object files generated for the static and the dynamic build, they have exactly the same size. That's the command I use to generate such a list:

```
ls -s `find -iname \*.o`|grep core
```

So, I thought, it must something in the linking phase. I took a look at the build.ninja file differences, and these are lines present only for the shared version:

```
LINK_FLAGS = -llog -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
LINK_LIBRARIES = lib/libopencv_features2d.so -ldl -lm -llog -ltbb lib/libopencv_flann.so lib/libopencv_highgui.so lib/libopencv_imgproc.so lib/libopencv_core.so
```

I do not think the additional libraries linked (dl, m, log, tbb) influence the final size, as they are all much smaller than the difference I found. Furthermore, I started to verify and for log there's only the .so available, and for tbb (100Kb) I have both shared and static version. BTW, I tried to build also without tbb.

To be 100% sure, I took the actual command line that was linking the object file, removed the `-no-undefined option`, and then removed all other options and linked libraries. The file size did not change, apart from when removing `-Wl,--gc-sections` which caused the file size to *increase* (it's some garbage collection option).

So, the only option that is left is a... linker bug?!? Does anybody have any idea what is happening?

**Some additional information:**

Compiler details:

```
 ./arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=./arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/opt/toolchain-arm17/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-androideabi
Configured with: /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.9/configure --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpfr=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpc=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-cloog=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-isl=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-ppl=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --disable-ppl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-isl-version-check --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --disable-libssp --enable-threads --disable-nls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdc__-v3 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-shared --disable-tls --disable-libitm --with-float=soft --with-fpu=vfp --with-arch=armv5te --enable-target-optspace --enable-initfini-array --disable-nls --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --with-sysroot=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/sysroot --with-binutils-version=2.24 --with-mpfr-version=3.1.1 --with-mpc-version=1.0.1 --with-gmp-version=5.0.5 --with-gcc-version=4.9 --with-gdb-version=7.6 --with-python=/usr/local/google/home/andrewhsieh/mydroid/ndk/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/python-config.sh --with-gxx-include-dir=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/include/c++/4.9 --with-bugurl=http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-bootstrap --enable-plugins --enable-libgomp --disable-libsanitizer --enable-gold --enable-graphite=yes --with-cloog-version=0.18.0 --with-isl-version=0.11.1 --enable-eh-frame-hdr-for-static --with-arch=armv5te --program-transform-name='s&^&arm-linux-androideabi-&' --enable-gold=default
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9 20140827 (prerelease) (GCC)
```

I also tried to see what would happen trying another version of the linker, but no changes in size

```
arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=arm-linux-androideabi-g++.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=lto-wrapper.exe
Target: arm-linux-androideabi
Configured with: /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.8/configure --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --target=arm-linux-androideabi --host=x86_64-pc-mingw32msvc --build=x86_64-lin
ux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpfr=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpc=/tmp/n
dk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-cloog=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-isl=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-ppl=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/
build/toolchain/temp-install --disable-ppl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-isl-version-check --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc+
+,-Bdynamic -lm' --disable-libssp --enable-threads --disable-nls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdc__-v3 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-shared --disable-tls --disable-libitm
 --with-float=soft --with-fpu=vfp --with-arch=armv5te --enable-target-optspace --enable-initfini-array --disable-nls --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --with-sysroot=/tmp/ndk-andrew
hsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/sysroot --with-binutils-version=2.24 --with-mpfr-version=3.1.1 --with-mpc-version=1.0.1 --with-gmp-version=5.0.5 --with-gcc-version=4.8 --with-gdb-version=7.6 --with-pytho
n=/usr/local/google/home/andrewhsieh/mydroid/ndk/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/python-config.sh --with-gxx-include-dir=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/include/c++/4.8 --with-bugurl=http://so
urce.android.com/source/report-bugs.html --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-bootstrap --enable-plugins --enable-libgomp --disable-libsanitizer --enable-gold --enable-graphite=yes --with-cloog-version=
0.18.0 --with-isl-version=0.11.1 --enable-eh-frame-hdr-for-static --with-arch=armv5te --program-transform-name='s&^&arm-linux-androideabi-&' --enable-gold=default
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8 (GCC)
```

**EDIT:**
As suggested by MarcB, I tried to [`strip`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/strip.htm) the library. The result is suprising (to me :) )

```
$ arm-linux-androideabi/bin/strip -g libopencv_core.so -o libopencv_core_stripped.so
$ ls -la *core*
6293308 Mar 13 10:40 libopencv_core.so
3224840 Mar 13 12:18 libopencv_core_stripped.so
```

**Where did all those debug symbols came out if the object files where compiled without -g (or even with -g0)?**

Note: the library stripped like that seem to be fully functional. The `nm -D` output of the stripped/unstripped library are the same, and `nm` output is just a few lines smaller (like 50 lines less out of 12000).

Just to be sure, I tried also to strip objects before linking, but their file does not change (it *increases* just a bit), and linking the "stripped" object files produces a library of the same big size of before.

Comment: debug symbols? have you tried stripping the files?

Comment: @MarcB I did not know about strip, thanks! I tried, please take a look at the result, it looks like you were on the right path!

Comment: Useful link https://www.technovelty.org/linux/stripping-shared-libraries.html

Answer (score 2):

Those are not *debug* symbols. They are regular linker symbols.

A shared library may have two sets of symbols: one is for linking, the other one is for dynamic loading. `strip` removes the first kind of symbols. <s>You cannot link with a stripped shared library</s>, but you can load it at run time normally (e.g if you use `dlopen`, or link with the library then strip it).

See `nm yourlib.so` and `nm -D yourlib.so` both before and after running `strip`.

**CORRECTION** it is possible to link with a stripped library. A good explanation about the two kinds of symbol tables is [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/ali/entry/inside_elf_symbol_tables).

Comment: 1) Why the strip guide says "-g -> Remove debugging symbols only."?
2) The output of `nm -D` for stripped and unstripped is identical. What does it mean?

Comment: ...And the stripped libraries seem to be fully functional, also at linking time. I have added the nm information to the question.

Comment: Another note: I can add -s to my linking options and I got even smaller and yet, apparently, usable libraries. I wonder why I can use -s for creating a .so, [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) it says "Remove all symbol table and relocation information from **the executable**."

Comment: You're right, it is possible to link with a striped library, see update.

Comment: A bit late now, but if you could add some essential points from the linked page, I could definitely accept the answer.